# What is the difference of this code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{        
  double aRate[10] = { 0.0, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.65, 0.8, 0.82, 0.97};
  int nAge = 0, i = 0, nFee = 1000;
  int a = 0;

  printf("%d  : \t%d \n", i, (int)(nFee*aRate[2]));
  return 0;
}
```

The result of this code is 0 : 250, as expected, but if I omit the parentheses like this,

```
printf("%d  : \t%d \n", i, (int)nFee*aRate[2]);
```

then the result is 0 : 0.

Why are

```
printf("%d  : \t%d \n", i, (int)(nFee*aRate[2]));
```

and

```
printf("%d  : \t%d \n", i, (int)nFee*aRate[2]);
```

different?

Is it related to order of priority?

Comment: It is related to UB, you are reading the low 32 bit of a double in the second case. 250.000 is *406f400000000000* in *IEEE754*.

Comment: it's the differences of parenthesis. in first attempt you cast the value of `nFree*aRate[2]` to int and then you print it. Your second attempt is `double` then you can't use `%d` for printing the value

Comment: Doesn't your compiler issue  a warning for the 2nd case?

Comment: Enable compiler warnings and pay heed to them!

Comment: I wonder about the down votes. This is a complete question.

Comment: To alk, Yes. I use visual studio 2013, and It doesn't warn.

Comment: @mathcom yes, VS doesn't warn when printf arguments don't match the format specifiers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of `(int)nFee*aRate[2]` is `double`, because it's the same as `((int)nFee)*aRate[2]` because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and the result of a multiplication of a `double` and an `int` is promoted to `double`. Therefore you are using `%d` as format specifier for a `double` which yields in undefined behaviour.

The type of `(int)(nFee*aRate[2])` is `int` therefore `%d` as format specifier is correct and you get the exepected result of 250 (0.25 * 1000).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's related to the parentheses.  The `(int)` binds very tightly, so in the second example it casts nFee to integer, which is a bit pointless as it's already an integer.  The `*` then multiplies int and double, producing double.
In the first example, the parenthesised expression `(nFee*aRate[2])`, which is of type double, is cast to integer by the `(int)`.

Here's a [table of the operator precedences](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).